# AJAX fails sending to PHP

Tags: php, ajax

I am trying to send form information from index.html to output.php (both are in the same directory) but i get this error:

```
Warning: Unknown: failed to open stream: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

Fatal error: Unknown: Failed opening required 'C:/xampp/htdocs/Tese_João/test-searchMYSQL/output.php' (include_path='.;C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in Unknown on line 0
```

**If you can help me too, with this code i only can get the advantages of AJAX by pressing ENTER or clicking outside the search box and not by just writing in the search box, anyone knows how to solve this ?**

**index.html:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title> Escolha de molecula</title>

<script>
    function showUser(str) {
        if (str=="") {
            document.getElementById("ajax").innerHTML="";
            return;
        } 

        if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
            // code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        } else { // code for IE6, IE5
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }

        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
            if (xmlhttp.status==200) {
                document.getElementById("ajax").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

        var txq=document.getElementById("textquery").value; 
        xmlhttp.open("POST","output.php?",true); 
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");            
        xmlhttp.send("textquery=" + txq); 
    }
</script>

</head>


<body>
    <h1 style="text-align:center;font-size: 60px"> 
        Search for molecule in our database 
    </h1>
    <hr>
        <p style="color:blue">
        <q>
            I have lived much of my life among molecules. They are good company.
        </q>
        George Wald
        </p>
    <hr>

    <p style="font-family:verdana">
        just write something in the search bar and it will retrieve it    <br>
        More information at: <a href="http://xldb.fc.ul.pt/" target="_blank">http://xldb.fc.ul.pt/</a>        
    </p>


    search: <input type="text"  id="textquery" onchange="showUser()" ><br> 

    </form>

    <br>

    <div id="ajax"><b>search results are displayed here</b></div> 
</body>
</html>
```

**output.php:**

```
<?php

$con=mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1","","","ulchemd");
    // Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$pesquisa =mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST['textquery']);
$resposta = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * from target WHERE molecule.target_text like '%$pesquisa%' ");

echo " <b> Search results:";




echo "<table border='5'>
<tr>
<th>ID</th>
<th>target_type</th>
<th>name</th>
<th>text</th>
</tr>";


while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($resposta)) { 
//este while vai buscar cada linha da tabela num ciclo como um cursor
  echo "<tr>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['tid'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['target_type'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
  echo "<td>" . $row['target_text'] . "</td>";
  echo "</tr>";
}

echo "</table>";

mysqli_close($con);
?>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Where is your `output.php` exactly?

Comment: in C:/xampp/htdocs/Tese_João/test-searchMYSQL/output.php

Comment: Is your both file are in same web directory?

Comment: yes, both are in C:/xampp/htdocs/Tese_João/test-searchMYSQL

Comment: Can you share full code of output.php?

Comment: In your code i dont see a place where you have included such a file in php. post the full code.

Comment: Yes, I've tested on my localhost, and if both file are in the same directory, then everything is works.

Comment: in this line : xmlhttp.open("POST","output.php?",true);

Comment: What you posted, that is a PHP error not a js error. Somewhere you want to include this `output.php`.

Comment: @lolka_bolka i found out that is all due to having João, not Joao in the directory , it looks like the source of error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As in your question/code there is no such type of error or exception in both files `index.html` and `output.php.`

According to error some where you are trying to import file in your code. So please share your full code.

Also you can try by changing you `output.php` file path as below.

```
xmlhttp.open("POST","http://localhost/projectName/output.php",true);
```

Comment: I found out the solution :) the Path C:/xampp/htdocs/Tese_João/test-searchMYSQL must be C:/xampp/htdocs/Tese_Joao/test-searchMYSQL